# How to open an activity in each case

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a menu in Action bar so i want in each case to open an activity. I cant figure out how to do it. My first activity is about us (just a textview)

```
//Override method for main menu
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about_us:
        //open AboutUsActivity

        return(true);
    case R.id.about_measures:
        //add the function to perform here
        return(true);
    case R.id.feedback:
        //add the function to perform here
        return(true);
    case R.id.rate:
        //add the function to perform here
        return(true);
}
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Comment: I tried  case R.id.home:
    startActivity(new Intent(main.this, map.class)); but is crashes

Comment: can you post your menu.xml and `onCreateOptionsMenu()`? and your logcat of crash

Comment: @UpendraShah Code works it was crashed because i forgot to add activity in manifest.

Comment: Okay.. Its good you solved your question by yourself. @Angelbreath

Answer (score 0):

You Can just pass your intent to class on which you want to open.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
Intent intent;
switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about_us:
        //open AboutUsActivity
        intent = new Intent(this, aboutUsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return true;

    case R.id.about_measures:
        //add the function to perform here
        intent = new Intent(this, aboutMeasuresActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return true;

    case R.id.feedback:
        //add the function to perform here
        intent = new Intent(this, feedbackActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return true;

    case R.id.rate:
        //add the function to perform here
        intent = new Intent(this, rateActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return true;
  }
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply intent which specifies your target activity and context of your current activity. Something like this:

```
case R.id.about_us:
    //open AboutUsActivity
    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
    return(true);
```